# Shadow is cut off in some angles in Cascade Shadow Map

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I am adding csm to my project, it work well all the day until I add sponza to my project.
When I look down, it works ok.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD7Ni.jpg)

But when I look up or, look behind. It turns weird.
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDMqU.jpg)
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ijj3.jpg)

following is my code to generate view and proj matrix:

```
glm::mat4 lightViewMat = glm::lookAt(frustumCenter -  lightDir , frustumCenter, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        

        float minX = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
        float maxX = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
        float minY = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
        float maxY = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
        float minZ = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
        float maxZ = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
        for (const auto& v : frustumCorners) {
            const auto trf = lightViewMat * glm::vec4(v, 1.0f);
            minX = std::min(minX, trf.x);
            maxX = std::max(maxX, trf.x);
            minY = std::min(minY, trf.y);
            maxY = std::max(maxY, trf.y);
            minZ = std::min(minZ, trf.z);
            maxZ = std::max(maxZ, trf.z);
        }
        float zMult = 50.f;
        if (minZ >= 0) {
            minZ /= zMult;
        } else {
            minZ *= zMult;
        }
        if (maxZ < 0) {
            maxZ /= zMult;
        } else {
            maxZ *= zMult;
        }
        glm::mat4 lightOrthoMat = glm::ortho(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ  );
```

Here is how I select Index in shader:

```
uint cascadeIndex = 0;
    vec3 viewPos = (uboScene.view * vec4(worldPos, 1.0f)).xyz;
    for (uint i = 0; i < CSM_COUNT - 1; i++){
        if (viewPos.z < csm.cascadeSplits[i]) {
            cascadeIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

And I have enabled PCF.
Can somebody tell me where went wrong :-( ? it bothers me for a very long time.